# What's the counterpart in Java of C#'s @ string literal?

Tags: c#, java, string-literals

C# has the [@ string literal](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/03/06/the-c-string-literal) to flexibly handle escape characters in strings. Is there anything like that in Java?

Comment: Not all features of Java are available in C# and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't.  You'll need to escape your strings.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a verbatim string literal.
Java does not have such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

If only I had a nickle for every time I need this in Java...

If you're doing a Regex operation consider `Pattern.quote` as a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Java supports path separators from UNIX which don't need to be escaped. e.g.

```
"c:/my/file.txt"
```

works fine on windows (and unix if you have a directory called `c:`)

The chose to use `\` rather than `/` as a path separator like just about every other operating system before or since, is a pet hate of mine. ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

Comment: I don't think that has much to do with Java itself - i.e. the above also works fine in Windows itself. And then sadly there were backcomp reasons in Windows which hindered them to use the backslash - actually the original developers weren't that happy with that themselves and included the possibility to change the path separator itself if you really wanted..